# FPSE alternative to publish on IIS7

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7, publish

We are migrating from **IIS6** to **IIS7**. I usually publish web applications on server using FPSE method. So I'm trying to install FPSE extension followiong [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/frontpage-server-extensions/installing-the-frontpage-server-extensions-on-iis) guide, but something doesn't work.

No **"MSSharePointAppPool"** application pool or **"FrontPage Server Administration website"** are created, so I'm wondering if there is an alternative to publish projects directly from Visual Studio 2010. Can you suggest me some other method to avoid manual copy of the publish folder into `wwwroot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you file system deployment method.

1. Configure the deployment by precising the target location on your web server
2. Save the publication profile.
3. Publish your web site on the server.
4. Configure the iis web Site on the server.

You can now republish in this folder using the saved profile.  You don't need FPSE on your server.